# I can't figure out how to make this function work properly

Tags: python, function

so im trying to create a function for my game in pycharm but i cannot figure out how to make this specific function work properly. what im trying to do is as follows: i want to make a functon called wall. this will make a wall tile and a rect appear. i have that done. however, the second part requires me to be able to define a width and a height for it. as it is a small but tileable img, i want to be able to define how many tiles down, and how many tiles right, so it will make a square or a rectangle of some sort. here is the code:

```
def wall(x, y, length,height,):
length = 0
height = 0
pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, (x, y, 32, 32), 0)
screen.blit(wall_surf, (x, y))
for length in range(length):
    wall(x + 32, y, 1, 1)
for height in range(height):
    wall(x, y + 32, 1, 1)
```

and here is the command i want to be able to use:

```
wall(0, 0, 2, 2)
```

ideally, this should make a 2 x 2 square at the top corner. the length and height are the second two numbers, the x and y are the first.

unfortunately, the for loop does not work for either of them. all the code does rn is make a single tile in the top left.
please explain simplistically, as i am just starting to code with python.

edit: here is the new code:

```
length = 0
height = 0

x = 0
y = 0

def wall(x, y, length,height,):
pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, (x, y, 32, 32), 0)
screen.blit(wall_surf, (x, y))

for l in range(length):
    wall(x + 32, y + height, 1, 1)
```

ok, with the new code that @picklepick has given me, i get an error: line 64, in 
wall(x, y)
TypeError: wall() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'rows' and 'cols'

i havent changed wall to my_draw_rect though.

Comment: After the function is invoked, you immediately set `length` and `height` to 0. `range(0)` doesn't do anything. Also you're calling `wall()` recursively (inside `wall()` itself that won't work either.

Comment: the length and height are the second numbers. edit: shoot im stupid

Comment: I can see that, but the first thing your function does, is setting the two values two 0 on line 2, and 3. So no matter what values you pass to `wall`, height and length will always be 0.

Comment: ok, i got rid of the l= 0 and h = 0 but now nothing is showing up in the tl

Comment: Also your loops are a mess: you use the same variable both as the itetator and the range: for **length** in range(**length**)? Use `for l in range(length)`.

Comment: ok, im not too well versed in all this, so i didnt know, but even after that, nothing is on the screen

Comment: Also instead of recursively calling `wall` create two loops outside of `wall`, `for l in range(length): for h in range(height): wall(x + l * 32, y + h * 32, 1, 1)`, and remove the recursive calls. This iterates over the matrix of all squares like this: [python nested for-loops](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_for_nested.asp)
Update your question to reflect these changes.

Comment: but doing that makes it so that python no longer knows what length and height is

Comment: well you would have to set length and height before the loops. Please update your question, to show the changes

Comment: also indentation... the lines meant to be inside `wall` function should be indented

Comment: the lines inside the wall are indented but stackoverflow has changed it. its rly annoying

Comment: okay, what now?

Comment: code blocks in stack overflow have to be double-indented, i.e. take your existing indented code and indent every line by an extra 4 spaces more than it already is

Comment: @2wen no it's not indented right, it's explained here: [SO markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting as an answer because it's hard to show in comments. This should get you started. You'll need to modify and test it yourself in order to understand how it works. Update your question when you're stuck again.

I changed the variable names for length & height to better reflect what's going on

```py
# draw 5x5 rects
rows = 5
cols = 5

# this should make the nested loops a bit clearer
for x in range(rows):
  for y in range(cols):
   print(x, y)
```

Next, instead of just printing the values you want to draw rectangles with the given coordinates:

```py
# this should make the nested loops a bit clearer
for x in range(rows):
  for y in range(cols):
    my_draw_rect(x, y) # this would be your (improved) wall()
```

`my_draw_rect()` would be your function that actually draw's the matrix of rectangles. It takes a x and y position and then draws a square at that position. There are many threads on this website (and many others) that show how to draw a square.

I haven't used pygame in a while but your wall would look something like:

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

SIZE = 500, 200
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GRAY = (150, 150, 150)
ROWS = 5
COLS = 5

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill(GRAY)
    for x in range(ROWS):
        for y in range(COLS):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, (x * 15, y * 15, 10, 10))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()



# this should look something like this:
# [][][][][]
# [][][][][]
# [][][][][]
# [][][][][]
# [][][][][]
```

I quickly wrote this based on the [pygame documentation](https://pygame.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rect/rect.html), when you start coding it's usually helpful to first write the same code as in the examples to get you used to it.

Comment: thank you so much, but i have one more question: what would my_draw_rect look like.? Fo i change it?

Comment: I added the draw example, does this help?

Comment: im still getting the error :line 63, in <module>
    for y in (cols):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: can you show the code? are you using `range()`?

Comment: like, the entire code?

Comment: here : for x in range(rows):
    for y in (cols):
        wall(x, y)

Comment: I forgot the `range()` in my example... I added it :)

Comment: nothing is appearing on the screen now GURYRYUXE

Comment: Maybe the rects are to small, use larger values for 1, 1 like 10, 10? Or post your entire code otherwise it's hard to guess what's going on

Comment: I've updated the last code cell, it's working fine for me now. Let me know if you're still running into problems